# how to create a notification trigger out of a selective weekday date that repeats weekly until a condition is met- swift

Tags: swift, repeat, uilocalnotification, weekday, reminders

I am building a medication reminder app and wanted to ask a few questions if anyone could answer some of them that would be great.

I want my app to allow the user to set a selected weekday date (Monday - Sunday). the user can then set the time in which they wish to take their medication (the user can set as many times as they like, of course, this depends on how many dosages they would need to take). then the user can type in the total amount of pills there are in the package.

***know here is the problem - I have no idea how to do the following things.***

1:  creating a selective date for only  weekdays and creating a notification  trigger out of the list of weekdays that the user has set

2: set more than one-timer on a date - for example, I want to take my medication Monday, and Tuesday at 2:00 pm and 6:00 am. - This means I want my app to notify the user every Monday at 2 pm and 6 am and Tuesday at 2 pm and 6 am

3: Create a notification trigger that goes through the list of weekdays and times and will keep repeating it WEEKLY until the medication runs out. (note* as I mentioned before I will ask the user how many pills are in the package and in addition I will ask the number of tablets they need to take, which I will create a function that will subtract from that total by the number of tablets every time the notification has triggered. the app will stop notifying the user when the total amount of pills has reached 0

****if anyone could give me a hint or anything that could help me that would be great. - Note* I am not asking anyone to create the app for me just help me get started****

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use the Calendar component. It has a bunch of functionalities that can help you do calendar related work. Here's the documentation page for weekdays https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/component/weekday
2. With the help of the Calendar mentioned above and Date you can make the calculations you need and save the times in UserDefaults, in a local database or on a server. Here is the documentation page for Date https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date
3. This can be achieved multiple ways, either having the calculations done on a server or locally on the phone. There are a lot of things to say here, so you could just google how to make reminder apps or todo apps or alarm apps etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The following advice is only good for quick prototyping.*

> Creating a selective date for only weekdays and creating a notification trigger out of the list of weekdays that the user has set

These are two different problems:

A) Create a way for the user to select one or more days in the weekday only.

For this point there are different approaches.

Once approach is to use a multi-select buttons: `[M][T][W][Th][F]`.

If you apply a unique value to each button, such as `1 2 4 8 16`, then you can store just one value that represent the status of that weekday.

For example, the value 19 means:

- Can you substract 19 from 16? Yes. Then, `_ _ _ _ F`. You have 3 left.
- Can you substract 3 from 8? No. Skip.
- Can you substract 3 from 4? No. Skip.
- Can you substract 3 from 2? Yes. Then, `_ T _ _ _ F`. You have 1 left.
- Can you substract 1 from 1? Yes. Then, `M T _ _ _ F`. You have zero. Done.

With this appoarch you exchange less space for more processing power.

Else, you can have a table in the database that has a unique id, and a column for each day. That unique id is used as a foreign id by other tables.

B) Create a notification that checks the days of the weekday that the user has selected.

This can be done by using the logic above; however, in devices like iPhone and Android, you mind need to learn how to do a *background service* to do this checking.

> Set more than one-timer on a date - for example, I want to take my medication Monday, and Tuesday at 2:00 pm and 6:00 am. - This means I want my app to notify the user every Monday at 2 pm and 6 am and Tuesday at 2 pm and 6 am

For simplicity, you can have two tables in the database. The first table is users, in case you have more than one.

The second table are the times, in which one column needs to have a foreign key indication which users that timer belongs to.

You can either store the star datetime and the duration of the timer in seconds. With simple math, you can transform the seconds (or milliseconds if you need precision) in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Then, the background service just check this tables. If the alarm is between the current time and the start datetime and it is less than 24 hours, then you notify the user.

> Create a notification trigger that goes through the list of weekdays and times and will keep repeating it WEEKLY until the medication runs out. (note* as I mentioned before I will ask the user how many pills are in the package and in addition I will ask the number of tablets they need to take, which I will create a function that will subtract from that total by the number of tablets every time the notification has triggered. the app will stop notifying the user when the total amount of pills has reached 0.

The "repeating weekly" can be another column using a BIT (0 or 1) as a flag.

The pills is another table where you list them and their quantity.

In addition, since you can have the same pill with multiple users or timers, you need another table to related them. A tables, user_timer_pill, with columns similar to this:

`[unique_id][user_id][timer_id][pill_id]`

Now, it just a query that says: Based on this user_id and this timer_id, give me one or more pill_id(s).

Or, if you add to the pill table this foreign key user_timer_pill_id, you can find out one or more users to notify, also, you can find out which timers are affected so you can mark them in red or something.

Finally, my advice is: When working on a project break it down into big chunks, then each big chuck break it down into little chuncks. For example:

Let's say you decide to work with a database.

- How to create the database?
- How to create the tables?
- What are going to be the relationships between each table:

  - one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many?
- How to do a query with join tables?
- What are the restrictions of each column of each table?

The notification:

- The background service that checks continously for data to notify.
- The notification mechanism.
- The activity in which the person lands if the notification is selected.

The app organization: MVC, MVVM, MVP?

I recomend using some agile methodology to organize yourself. Research Scrum vs. Kanban.

Good luck.